# google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message with type 'tensorflow.GraphDef'

Tags: python-3.x, protocol-buffers, tensorflow-lite

I have a yolov4 pre-trained model, which has been extracted in '.pb' and tflite format, while i am testing it  SOM (system on module) which is ubuntu 18, i am getting following error:-

graph_def.ParseFromString(file_handle.read())
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message with type 'tensorflow.GraphDef'

---

code is following-

```
with tf.gfile.GFile(checkpoint_filename, "rb") as file_handle:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(file_handle.read())
```

P.s. This is working fine on my local computer.

python 3.7.15
tensorflow  2.5.0
protobuf 3.19.1

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!